# Where to git init for Java project?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, github

I've created workspace `TestWorkspace` and in it, I created project `Testing Project`(now which has `.settings`, `src`, `bin` folders and `.classpath`, `.project` files). I will add my code under this project and I want to host this project on gitHub. In order to do that, I'll have to `git init`

Where should I `git init`? In workspace folder `TestWorkspace` or project folder `Testing Project`? What is the ideal way so that going further I won't face issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Egit User guide:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide

> It is probably not a good idea to make a project the root folder of
>   your Repository
>
> The reason is that you will never be able to add another project to
>   this Repository, as the .project file will occupy the root folder; you
>   could still add projects as sub-folders, but this kind of project
>   nesting is known to cause lots of problems all over the place. In
>   order to add another project, you would have to move the project to a
>   sub-folder in the Repository and add the second project as another
>   sub-folder before you could commit this change.

It's not a good idea to `git init` in workspace folder TestWorkspace.

It is a good idea to keep your Repository outside of your Eclipse Workspace.

Comment: Thanks pier-alexandre-bouchard!

Comment: Also see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367583/how-to-initialize-git-for-a-new-eclipse-neon-java-project